# Some homework help needed. Python 2.7

Tags: algorithm, python-2.7, divide-and-conquer

I received this problem as one of my homework problems, and I'm catching my ears with it. I would like some help with it:

The problem of the cuts: A rectangular metal sheet plate, of Lp x Hp size, has n
holes, in integer coordinates points. Cut a piece of plate of  maximum surface, without holes, knowing that only parallel with the sides of the plate cuts are allowed.
Note: The coordinates of the holes are retained in two vectors vx[i] for the abscises holes
and vy[i] for ordinates (these vectors aren't certainly sorted, wholes being able to be stored in chronologycal order, for example). The initial rectangle, and then
rectangles that appear in the cutting process, are stored through the coordinates of the bottom left corner
(x, y) by length L and height h (each rectangle is identified through a set of 4 variables: x, y, L, h, by with the help of which the 4 corners coordinates are formed). We apply "Divide and conquer" technique.

What I have tried:

```
### [1,3] :vx (holes)




def cuts(x,y,L,h):
    for i in range(nrg):
        if vx[i] > x and vx[i] < x+L and vy[i] > y and vy[i] <y+h:
            found = True
            break
    if found:
        1: couts(x,y,L-vx[i],h)
        2: cuts(vx[i],y,L-vx[i]+x,h)
        3: cuts(L-vx[i],y,L-vx[i],h)
        4: cuts(x,h-y,L,h-y)
    else:
        ar = L*h
        if ar > arMax:
            arMax = ar

nrg = 2
vx[1] = [1,3]
vx[2] = [2,3]
[x,y,L,h]
sol[0] = x
sol[1] = y
sol[2] = L
sol[3] = h
```

Comment: Looks your initial attempt was submitted to `/dev/null` I'm afraid...

Comment: This sounds like an interesting homework problem - but you'd really want to do this on your own. A suggestion is to give this your best attempt. If you encounter some programming problem - you can then ask a more specific question.

Comment: I don't see anything about Python in your question.  I have retagged your question accordingly.

Comment: @ishmaelMakitla I have edited my post and added my try

Comment: @ics:  Where is your code falling short?  What's wrong with it?

Comment: @StevenRumbalski at the 12th line: Invalid syntax

Comment: @ics: Get rid of the `1:`, `2:`, etc.  They aren't proper syntax.  Also, I believe you mean `cuts` and not `couts`.  Other than that I have worked to understand your code.